# A hash function that returns a value interpreted as integer

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256

I am new in cryptography. I need to compute a hash of a string value represented as follows:
$name||i$ where $i$ is an integer.

I use the following pseudocode:

```
message = []byte(name||i)
hashize = 1536
// Using SHA256 full-domain-hash with 1536 bits
hashed = fdh.Sum(crypto.SHA256, hashize, message)
Print(hashed)
```

Here the hash is a vector of integer values. How can I have only one integer that represents the hash of the message?

Comment: This is a programming question and off-topic here. Use a bignumber library like GNU/GMP or Java's bignum etc. Simply google '"the language you are working" convert bytes to big integer'. byte since most of the libraries works in bytes.

Comment: Note that there is an accepted, cryptographically specific answer to this question so it seems that it **can** be on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the intention is to make an RSA-1536 (or Rabin) signature of *name* (as a string) and integer $i$ per [Full Domain Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash). Thus I answer, form a crypto standpoint, a rephrasing of the question as:

> How do I make a full-domain hash of the concatenation of a name (given as a string) and an integer, towards signing these per RSA-FDH.

In a nutshell, my recommendation is to make that as in RSA-PSS, but with a fixed salt.

An implementation of that could be

1. Express *name* and $i$ as a bytestring per ASN.1 [Distinguished Encoding Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) (DER). This will avoid ambiguities of string concatenation (so that name `foo` and integer `10` won't have the same hash as name `foo1` and integer `0`), and normalize the integer (so that integers `00` and `0` will result in the same hash). Formatting could be as a SEQUENCE (tag 16) with *name* as UTF8String (tag 12) then INTEGER (tag 2). See Burton S. Kaliski's [*A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER*](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) (RSA labs, 1993), which is enough for an implementer, except for [the UTF8String type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932062/903600).
2. Apply to the resulting bytestring the [EMSA-PSS transformation of PKCS#1v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=35) with SHA-256 hash, MGF1 with SHA-256 hash, $\text{emBits}=1536$, and fixed salt (e.g. 256 bits at zero). Part of that step includes hasing the input bytestring with SHA-256.
3. Convert the outcome to integer (per big-endian convention); this yields an integer as asked in the question.
4. Apply textbook RSA signature $x\mapsto x^d\bmod N$ (or the Rabin alternative).
5. Convert the integer outcome to a bytestring of $\left\lceil\text{emBits}/8\right\rceil=192$ bytes (per big-endian convention), yielding the signature.

Note: when targeting RSA, the combination of 2…5 is precisely signature per [RSASSA-PSS of PKCS#1v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=27), and implementations of that should be reusable directly, if they have an input for the salt or for the salt-generating method.

Comment: The implementation itself is off-topic here on crypto-SE, as noted in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/185660) and in our [help](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).